# In Camel how can I reload properties using Spring?

Tags: spring, apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I am using Spring and Camel 2.16 in Servicemix 7. I want the installed bundle to refresh after a property change. In Blueprint, there is the following way:

```
<cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="my-placeholders" update-strategy="reload">
...
</cm:property-placeholder>
```

How can I do the same in Spring?

Kind regards,

R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are interested about Spring DM and not Spring (ie, Spring extension in an OSGi container) :

You can't with Spring DM automatically refresh a context when managed properties are updated, but you can use Blueprint with Camel. Moreover, Spring DM is deprecated and not maintained, and blueprint is the spec to use to replace it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.